# Convert .pem files to .jks

Tags: openssl, certificate, keystore, pem, jks

I received the two private RSA keys in my mail and I copied and saved it as `validator.pem` and `user.pem` which I used to connect to remote server. This is working.

Now, I need to convert them to `.jks` files, but I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate


validator.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
----------------------------------------------------------
user.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----


openssl x509 -outform der -in your-cert.pem -out your-cert.crt

unable to load certificate
69095:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

I'm using Mac.

Comment: You need keytool (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html).

Answer (score -1):

The process to convert the files is at

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html

To convert the file to pkcs format, use below command. you will need CA certificates for this step:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Comment: I got only two .pem files (no cert or any other files), when it open , we can see "BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY" .

Comment: The question was about the `.jks` file format and not `.pfx`

Comment: @ValerioBozz They are the same thing

Comment: @dubvfan87 Really? Maybe it's useful to add a note about it in the answer