# Spring boot mongo tls cert

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, ssl

I have set up TLS in mongod.conf. I need to use spring boot to connect to my mongo which requires tls now. In MongoCompass, I set Certificate Authority, Client Certificate & Client Private Key to root-ca.pem, test.pem & test.pem accordingly and I am able to connect. How can i specify the root-ca.pem & test.pem correctly in mongoclientoptions to connect to my mongo?

This is my mongod.conf

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  tls:
    mode: requireTLS
    certificateKeyFile: C:\TLSServerMongo\test.pem
    CAFile: C:\TLSServerMongo\root-ca.pem
    clusterFile: C:\TLSServerMongo\test.pem
    allowInvalidCertificates: true
    FIPSMode : false
```

This is my mongoclientoptions

```
   @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
        MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true).sslEnabled(true);
        try {
//            String fileName = directory + RDS_COMBINED_CA_BUNDLE;
            String fileName = "C:\\TLSServerMongo\\test.pem";
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            // You could get a resource as a stream instead.

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is);

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ks.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
            ks.setCertificateEntry("caCert", caCert);

            tmf.init(ks);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            mongoClientOptions.sslContext(sslContext);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }


        return mongoClientOptions.build();
    }
```

This is my MongoClient

```
  public @Bean
    MongoClient mongoClient() {
        List<MongoCredential> allCred = new ArrayList<>();
        allCred.add(MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray()));
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient((new ServerAddress(this.myHost, this.myPort)), allCred, mongoClientOptions());
        client.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);

        return client;
    }
```

Comment: Both of those certificates should be passable via the standardized URI options.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a Good idea to create one single .jks file as a cert and use it in spring boot mongo client...

pls refre to this for converting your .pem cert into JKS [Convert .pem files to .jks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427828/convert-pem-files-to-jks)

Once you have the .jks in your keystore on your system then we can use it or you may follow this example to connect using jks...

[Connecting to MongoDB from spring boot app using ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355417/connecting-to-mongodb-from-spring-boot-app-using-ssl)

or
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206462/how-to-configure-ssl-mongodb-connection-in-yml-file-spring-boot

Hope it helps!